# Disable the highlighting of nodes and edges in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using cytoscape.js for displaying a graph pretty simular to this example: [Sample graph](http://jsbin.com/vehapineju/3/edit?html,js,output). But I don't want to have the selected nodes and edges highlighted (or framed). I had no success by checking the API so I hope someone can give me a hint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to HTML, you need to set your stylesheet appropriately for whatever visual effect you want:

You may find this relevant:

- http://js.cytoscape.org/#style
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/overlay
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/state

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the highlighting by setting the [overlay-opacity](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/overlay) property to `0` for all nodes & edges:

```
var graph = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: [/* ... */],
    options: {
        style: [
            {
                selector: 'node, edge',
                style: {
                    'overlay-opacity': 0,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
});
```